# Change colour of discount code dropdown on cart page in Luma - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, less, luma-theme

On the cart page in the Luma theme there is a dropdown that when clicked expands to allow you to enter a discount code.

What is the less variable to change this colour please?

[image: Cart Discount]

This is the CSS that is generated:

```
.paypal-review-discount .block > .title strong, .cart-discount .block > .title strong {
    color: #1979c3;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

and this is overriding the standard `.block .title strong` styles which is the correct colour.

Can anyone help with this please? I don't want to do override this with CSS.